# Win32 MFC window background image tiling when it shouldn't

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I'm making a sample Splash screen in `MFC` that does nothing but display a topmost borderless window that has an image as the background. I'm having a really weird issue that crops up on my friends computer but not mine, even though we're using the same OS. I've fixed the issue but I'd like some input as to why this could be happening on his machine and not mine and why the alternate version I've created works on both machines.

**Broken method 1 (works for me, not for him)**

```
BOOL Splash::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    if (!CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs))
        return FALSE;

    CBitmap bitmap; bitmap.LoadBitmap(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
    CBrush bitmapBrush; bitmapBrush.CreatePatternBrush(&bitmap);
    bitmap.DeleteObject();

    cs.style = WS_POPUP;
    cs.dwExStyle = WS_EX_TOPMOST;

    cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(0, 0, (HBRUSH)bitmapBrush.Detach());
    bitmapBrush.DeleteObject();

    return TRUE;
}
```

The above works perfectly fine on my 2 versions of Windows (Windows 7 and 10) and shows an off-centered, tiled bitmap on my friend's instance of Windows 7.

**Working method 2 (works on everything tested so far)**

```
void Splash::OnPaint()
{
    CRect window;
    this->GetClientRect(&window);

    PAINTSTRUCT paint = { 0 };
    CDC *dc = this->BeginPaint(&paint);

    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
    CBitmap *oldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(&this->m_SplashBitmap);

    dc->BitBlt(window.left, window.top, window.right, window.bottom, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    memDC.SelectObject(oldBitmap);
    memDC.DeleteDC();

    this->EndPaint(&paint);
}
```

The above code works on my Windows 7, Windows 10 and my friend's instance of Windows 7. Any idea why this is or what could be happening? Maybe my first iteration is done completely wrong?

Comment: According to the docs window classes can only use a physical brush for the background brush, and `CreatePatternBrush` returns a logical brush. Probably a fluke that it works at all, dependent on video card I imagine.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Could you link to this documentation you're talking about? I looked at the documentation for [WNDCLASSEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx) and [AfxRegisterWndClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cw5335z0.aspx), both say nothing about that and countless examples on the internet for setting a window background image use the same method I did. I couldn't find anything on that in the documentation for `CreatePatternBrush` either.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576(v=vs.85).aspx "*This member can be a handle to the **physical brush** to be used for painting the background, or it can be a color value*"

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm not entirely certain that actually matters. The `WNDCLASS` and `WNDCLASSEX` structures feed into the same window creation routines. `WNDCLASS` has been superseded by `WNDCLASSEX` and the `WNDCLASSEX` documentation does not say it needs to be a physical brush at all. From `WNDCLASSEX` documentation in the same paragraph you reference from `WNDCLASS`: "This member can be a handle to the brush to be used for painting the background, or it can be a color value", notice they removed the `physical` qualifier in the new documentation.

Comment: Could you add screenshots showing the result of method one on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Your friend's machine is running at a different DPI that yours and your app is not marked as DPI aware.

I assume you attempted to make the bitmap and window the same size with the expectation that exactly one copy of the bitmap would fill the window.

On one machine, with no DPI scaling, everything just works.

On another machine with DPI scaling, the window size will actually be scaled up.  The background drawing is probably done with a PatBlt, which doesn't get scaled; the pattern (brush) is just repeated as often as necessary to fill the area.

When you use BitBlt, windows will apply the same DPI scaling to the blit as it does to the Window, so it works whether or not scaling is on.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue since we both tested it on multiple DPI settings. In every case mine worked properly and his was tiled. The answer makes sense and should be what's going on but I don't see this when testing on both machines in multiple DPI settings.